# implicit inner joins - are they equal?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, inner-join

In my opinion these two SELECTs are exactly equal (but I want to rewrite the first for the second to help the optimizer in my case) - whatever data sits in tables a,b,c,d both SELECTs will produce exactly the same results. Do you agree? Thanks!

```
create table a (id number);
create table b (id number);
create table c (id number);
create table d (id number);

--Q1
select * from a,b,c,d
where a.id = b.id
and   a.id = c.id 
and   a.id = d.id;

--Q2
select * from a,b,c,d
where a.id = b.id
and   a.id = c.id 
and   a.id = d.id
      -- Q2 differs from Q1 only in the next 3 lines
and   b.id = c.id
and   b.id = d.id
and   c.id = d.id;
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Period.

Comment: +1 for Gordon's comment .comas produce the cartesian product of all 4 tables, causing terrible performance without a reason. Use `join`.

Comment: Yes, these are all equivalent.  You're joining all the tables on the same `id` columns.  Transitive property: `a=b, b=c --> a=c`

Comment: @Bonzay, comma joins are optimized to execute exactly the same as explicit joins. However, still bad programming. Modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax is easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I don't think any modern optimizer will generate a different plan for those two queries. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 11g

Comment: I am quite certain that both queries will use exactly the same execution plan in Oracle (which you can easily verify yourself)

Comment: Why wouldn't they be the same? What do you expect us to answer except "yes" & "because that's how SQL works"? Would that show that your reasoning is correct? Explain your reasoning.

Comment: Comma is implicit cross join. Inner join is (INNER) JOIN ON. There's no "implicit inner join". (Both inner & outer join give cross join on condition true. So comma is not "more" inner than outer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to address the question of whether those inequalities are *always* true.  The answer is "no", not in SQL.  Under most circumstances, they are equivalent.  The problem arises with implicit type conversion.

In particular, if `a.id` is a number and other columns are strings, then you have the situation where:

```
1 = '1'        -- true
1 = '1.00'     -- true
'1' = '1.00'   -- false
```

You can see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=56e396ed185538d7c2158fdc3426ffc1)) on this db<>fiddle.  It would be trivial to set this up using `JOIN`s, but since I am not going to write code that has commas in the `FROM` clause, I'll leave that exercise to you.

In practice, id's used for joins should be of the same type.  You cannot even declare a foreign key relationship if they are not.  That best practice aside, the two queries are not automatically equivalent.

Note:  This would be just as true if you used proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax, which I strongly, strongly encourage you to learn and use exclusively.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that both queries are equal when the ids are of the same type and also thank you for the very interesting note about type conversion and how it makes the queries not be alike. Yes, I write my queries in the standard syntax. Here, I am re-writing an old production query where I want to do minimal changes. So for my example I also used the old syntax that the code I inherited uses as maybe in the old syntax it could have been different from the new syntax. Call me a coward if you wish for just adding the conditions and not rewriting the old monster query :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, results will be exactly the same. To think of it algebraically, if a = b and b = c, then a = c. This means that the final three conditions in the second query are redundant.

I would say it is better to stick with the original query though. At best, the query optimizer will need to perform more comparisons.

Comment: And here you can play and test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b5757762cada2d34d0a44eb3f8934cd

Answer (score 1):

One would expect Oracle to apply the rules of [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) and use the information you've provided it to prove that the excess predicates are unnecessary ([and it often does so, as I've shown in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/28/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/)), but it doesn't seem to do it in this particular case (without constraints or indexes). Getting the execution plans for these two queries:

```sql
SELECT s.sql_id, p.*
FROM v$sql s, TABLE (
  dbms_xplan.display_cursor (
    s.sql_id, s.child_number, 'ALLSTATS LAST'
  )
) p
WHERE s.sql_text LIKE '%a,b,c,d%'
```

Yields:

```
SQL_ID  d54mttn9psd29, child number 0
-------------------------------------
--Q2
 select * from a,b,c,d
 where a.id = b.id
 and   a.id = c.id 
 and 
  a.id = d.id
       -- Q2 differs from Q1 only in the next 3 lines
 
and   b.id = c.id
 and   b.id = d.id
 and   c.id = d.id
 
Plan hash value: 3564259801
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | E-Rows |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |        |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN           |      |      1 |  1068K|  1068K|  240K (0)|
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN          |      |      1 |  1209K|  1209K|  505K (0)|
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN         |      |      1 |  1506K|  1506K|  461K (0)|
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |      1 |       |       |          |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |      1 |       |       |          |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |      1 |       |       |          |
|   7 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | D    |      1 |       |       |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL_ID  3zzwv0z5tq84f, child number 0
-------------------------------------
--Q1
 select * from a,b,c,d
 where a.id = b.id
 and   a.id = c.id 
 and 
  a.id = d.id
 
Plan hash value: 255250992
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | E-Rows |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      |        |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN             |      |      1 |  1068K|  1068K|  178K (0)|
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN |      |      1 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|      |      1 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | B    |      1 |       |       |          |
|   5 |     BUFFER SORT        |      |      1 | 73728 | 73728 |          |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |      1 |       |       |          |
|   7 |    BUFFER SORT         |      |      1 | 73728 | 73728 |          |
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | D    |      1 |       |       |          |
|   9 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL    | A    |      1 |       |       |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which is surprising. Without having calculated statistics on the empty tables, the E-Rows value is correct, but the memory estimates are way off, and different for the two queries.

This doesn't mean that one approach is *always* better or even different from the other, but it *might be*. E.g. when I add actual data to the tables and calculate statistics:

```sql
INSERT INTO a SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000;
INSERT INTO b SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000;
INSERT INTO c SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000;
INSERT INTO d SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000;

BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('TEST', 'A');
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('TEST', 'B');
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('TEST', 'C');
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('TEST', 'D');
END;
```

Then, I'm getting the same execution plans with hash joins, not with merge joins:

```
SQL_ID  d54mttn9psd29, child number 0
-------------------------------------
--Q2
 select * from a,b,c,d
 where a.id = b.id
 and   a.id = c.id 
 and 
  a.id = d.id
       -- Q2 differs from Q1 only in the next 3 lines
 
and   b.id = c.id
 and   b.id = d.id
 and   c.id = d.id
 
Plan hash value: 2782485219
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | E-Rows |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |        |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN           |      |      1 |  1836K|  1836K| 2032K (0)|
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN          |      |      1 |  2161K|  2161K| 2145K (0)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |  10000 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN         |      |  10000 |  2546K|  2546K| 2211K (0)|
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |  10000 |       |       |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |  10000 |       |       |          |
|   7 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | D    |  10000 |       |       |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL_ID  3zzwv0z5tq84f, child number 0
-------------------------------------
--Q1
 select * from a,b,c,d
 where a.id = b.id
 and   a.id = c.id 
 and 
  a.id = d.id
 
Plan hash value: 388154631
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | E-Rows |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |        |       |       |          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN           |      |  10000 |  2546K|  2546K| 2099K (0)|
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | D    |  10000 |       |       |          |
|*  3 |   HASH JOIN          |      |  10000 |  2546K|  2546K| 2146K (0)|
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |  10000 |       |       |          |
|*  5 |    HASH JOIN         |      |  10000 |  2546K|  2546K| 2211K (0)|
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |  10000 |       |       |          |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |  10000 |       |       |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The learning here is the same as always. Don't trust your intuition. Don't trust any old blog posts on the Internet. Check out execution plans and measure.

I used Oracle Database 18c Express Edition for this.