# Replace multiple value for String column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and struggling to do this.
I have input like below in two data frames
(Journey,country_code mappinng) and need to generate another data frame like the expected result.

**Journey:-**

| ID | journey |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | US->UK->IN |
| 2 | UK->IN->CH |

**country_code mappinng:-**

| Code | Country |
| --- | --- |
| US | United States |
| IN | India |
| MY | Malaysia |
| UK | United kingdom |
| CH | China |

**Expected output:- **

| ID | journey | Journey_LongName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US->UK->IN | United States->United kingdom->India |
| 2 | UK->IN->CH | United kingdom->India->China |

Country mapping is dynamic and the order of the journey shouldn't changed in the Journey_LongName field.If any of you solved this problem or have an idea,plz share your input.
Thanks
Dhana

Comment: spark version ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a join after all, but the tricky part is to keep the order. I used `transform` to keep the index so that order can be maintained. At the end the index is discarded using `transform` again.

Here the dataframes are called `journey` and `country`. Result is called `df`.

```
df = journey.selectExpr(
    'ID', 'journey',
    """explode(
          transform(
              split(journey, '->'),
              (x, i)-> struct(x as Code, i as index)
          )
      ) as countries"""
).select(
    'ID', 'journey', 'countries.*'
).join(
    country,
    'Code'
).drop('Code').groupBy('ID').agg(
    F.first('journey').alias('journey'), 
    F.array_sort(
        F.collect_list(
            F.array('index', 'Country')
        )
    ).alias('journey_long')
).selectExpr(
    'ID', 'journey',
    """concat_ws(
           '->',
           transform(journey_long, x -> x[1])
       ) as journey_long"""
)

df.show(20,0)
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|ID |journey   |journey_long                        |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|United States->United kingdom->India|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|United kingdom->India->China        |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using spark-sql:

Given input-1

```
val df1=spark.sql(""" with t1 (
select 1 c1 , 'US->UK->IN'  c2 union all
select 2 c1 , 'UK->IN->CH' c2 )
select c1 id, c2 journey from t1 
"""
)
df1.show(false)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

+---+----------+
|id |journey   |
+---+----------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|
+---+----------+
```

Input-2:

```
val df2=spark.sql(""" with t1 (
select 'US' c1 , 'United States'  c2 union all
select 'IN' c1 , 'India'  c2 union all
select 'MY' c1 , 'Malaysia'  c2 union all
select 'UK' c1 , 'United kingdom'  c2 union all
select 'CH' c1 , 'China'  c2
)
select c1 code, c2 country from t1 
"""
)
df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

+----+--------------+
|code|country       |
+----+--------------+
|US  |United States |
|IN  |India         |
|MY  |Malaysia      |
|UK  |United kingdom|
|CH  |China         |
+----+--------------+
```

Enable cross-join

```
spark.sql(" set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true ")
```

Using posexplode, collect_list and array_sort in the spark.sql

```
spark.sql("""
select id, journey, concat_ws('->', array_sort(collect_list((e1,country))).country) result from
(
select id, journey, e1, e2, code, country  from 
(select id, journey, posexplode(split(journey,"->")) (e1,e2) from df1  ) t1 cross join 
(select code, country from df2) t2 
where code=e2 ) t3
group by id, journey
order by ID
""")
.show(false)

+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|id |journey   |result                              |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|United States->United kingdom->India|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|United kingdom->India->China        |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: To quote Gordon Linoff, "Never use commas in the FROM clause. Always use proper, explicit, standard JOIN syntax." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117714/implicit-inner-joins-are-they-equal#comment102624361_58117714

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using nested transform() higher order function that is available in spark 2.4 onwards

```
df1.show(false)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

+---+----------+
|id |journey   |
+---+----------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|
+---+----------+

df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

+----+--------------+
|code|country       |
+----+--------------+
|US  |United States |
|IN  |India         |
|MY  |Malaysia      |
|UK  |United kingdom|
|CH  |China         |
+----+--------------+


spark.sql("""
select id, journey,  concat_ws('->',flatten(transform( split(journey,"->") ,(x,i) -> transform(s1, (y,j) -> (y[x]) )  )))  result from df1, 
( select collect_list(map(code,country)) s1 from df2 )
""")
.show(false)

+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|id |journey   |result                              |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|United States->United kingdom->India|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|United kingdom->India->China        |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
```

The query can be further shortened by moving the collect_list to transform input

```
spark.sql("""
select id, journey, concat_ws('->',flatten(transform( split(journey,"->") ,(x,i) -> transform( (select collect_list(map(code,country)) s1 from df2 ), (y,j) -> (y[x]) )  )))  result from df1 
""")
.show(false)

+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|id |journey   |result                              |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|United States->United kingdom->India|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|United kingdom->India->China        |
+---+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the aggregate() and transform() HOFs:

Input-1:

```
val df1=spark.sql(""" with t1 (
select 1 c1 , 'US->UK->IN'  c2 union all
select 2 c1 , 'UK->IN->CH' c2 )
select c1 id, c2 journey from t1 
"""
)
df1.show(false)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

+---+----------+
|id |journey   |
+---+----------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|
+---+----------+
```

Input-2:

```
val df2=spark.sql(""" with t1 (
select 'US' c1 , 'United States'  c2 union all
select 'IN' c1 , 'India'  c2 union all
select 'MY' c1 , 'Malaysia'  c2 union all
select 'UK' c1 , 'United kingdom'  c2 union all
select 'CH' c1 , 'China'  c2
)
select c1 code, c2 country from t1 
"""
)

df2.show(false)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

+----+--------------+
|code|country       |
+----+--------------+
|US  |United States |
|IN  |India         |
|MY  |Malaysia      |
|UK  |United kingdom|
|CH  |China         |
+----+--------------+
```

Using the HOFs

```
spark.sql("""
 with t1 ( select map(code, country) m1 from df2 ),
      t2 ( select collect_list(m1) m2 from t1 ) ,
      t3 ( select aggregate(m2, cast(map() as map<string,string>), (acc,i) ->  map_concat(acc,i)) m3 from t2 ),
      t4 ( select *, transform( split(journey,'->'), x -> (select m3 from t3)[x] )  j1 from df1 )
      select id, journey, j1, concat_ws('->',j1) j2 from t4 
""").show(false)

+---+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|id |journey   |j1                                    |j2                                  |
+---+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|[United States, United kingdom, India]|United States->United kingdom->India|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|[United kingdom, India, China]        |United kingdom->India->China        |
+---+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

You can use struct() instead of map() and thus replace the aggregate() with the map_from_entries()

```
spark.sql("""
 with t1 ( select struct(code, country) m1 from df2 ),
      t2 ( select collect_list(m1) m2 from t1 ) ,
      t3 ( select map_from_entries(m2) m3 from t2 ),
      t4 ( select *, transform( split(journey,'->'), x -> (select m3 from t3)[x] )  j1 from df1 )
      select id, journey, j1, concat_ws('->',j1) j2 from t4 
""").show(false)


+---+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|id |journey   |j1                                    |j2                                  |
+---+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|1  |US->UK->IN|[United States, United kingdom, India]|United States->United kingdom->India|
|2  |UK->IN->CH|[United kingdom, India, China]        |United kingdom->India->China        |
+---+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```